# Page looks good in most browsers except in IE7...why

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The following page looks good in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE6 and IE8... **but it looks bad  in IE7**. I don't have IE7 but I need to fix this issue because someone seen it in IE7 and it looks bad. Does anyone has any idea why this page renders different in IE7?...and what is the solution to make it display correctly?

http://www.aetna.com/2009annualreport/mainBoard.html

Problem:

When you click on the "Board of Directors" or "Management Team" link and the listing table panel opens up, the far right third of the panel is getting cut off. Also some information appears to be missing in the cells.

Thanks,
Attila

Comment: Are you aware of those JS syntax errors? And that the `javascript:` pseudoprotocol is considered poor practice?

Comment: In IE8, hit f12 to open developer tools, then select `Browser Mode: IE7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem disappears when I remove `overflow: hidden;` from the `.boardSlider` class.

Look like another [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) bug.

Comment: Removing the overflow:hidden; tag helped to get rid of the clipping issue on the right...but some of the text in the Board Members panel are still missing in the table cells...any ideas why?

Comment: Giving the `#boardPanel` a fixed width of `990px` also solves the problem (as suggested by vinhboy).

Comment: The missing text (visibility issue) related to the italic formatting of the texts. It seems all the italics were missing and are overflowing container elements in IE7 and therefore rendered invisible...weird issue. As soon as I set all italics font styles to overflow:auto; then it forced IE7 to display them. It seems easy now but it took me 4 hours to figure this out...I want 4 hours of my life back from Microsoft! :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. use a css-reset

But also... use the validator.

http://validator.w3.org/

I used the validator and found this:

```
Polo Ralph Lauren Corporation</p></li>
```

Notice the misplaced `li` ?

Also add this to `#boardPanel`

```
{ width: 990px; }
```

Comment: CSS reset is not a solution, it's a sledgehammer for the lazy (and doesn't solve this particular problem). The misplaced `li` is a good find, but not the root cause of this particular problem as well.

Comment: the css reset will solve a lot of other cross browser problems in his css. it's sort of required.

check answer for update with new fix.

Comment: CSS reset doesn't solve haslayout bugs. It only solves problems for pixelpurists who don't want to set a default margin for every block element himself.

Comment: I don't think you noticed the `sledgehammer for the lazy` part.

Answer (score 2):

All browsers render web pages differently.  There is no one solution that will always make everything look exactly the same across all browsers.  The best option is to start with a browser such as firefox or safari when you are testing and then tweak your css for internet explorer as you go along.  One common technique is to use a CSS reset to try to abstract differences between browsers.

If you don't have IE7 on your machine you can test in it using http://spoon.net/browsers to see what your page will look like or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565505/whats-the-best-way-to-do-cross-browser-testing) for more suggestions.

Comment: He has IE8, so he can see what it looks like in IE7 using developer tools.

Comment: @sr pt, that is a really good suggestion.  I completely forgot about that as an option.  You should put it in an answer

Comment: I don't have IE8, I have just reviewed the site on IE8 on a friend's machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Adobe Browser Lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html). Very cool and very efficient and the best part is it's free (not anymore thanks for the headsup). It not only has various browser options but also OS options.

HTH

Comment: It's not free any more - the limited trial has finished.

Comment: It is cool but limited, because it only allows to take a snapshot of the page as it displays first without interacting with the page. So in my case I can't see the problem because the sliding panel is closed when you enter the page and I can't click the button to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - why not use DIVS and floats - you should never really use tables for layout purposes (particularly as it's 2010). Especially dynamically changing layouts. Tables are cross-browser hell, particularly when expanding / contracting using JavaScript and, from a purist's point of view, you are not displaying tabular data, so why use a table?

Comment: Also, Javascript error in "annualReport_scripts.js" (rogue </script> tag). But I'd go with removing the 'overflow:hidden' issue and definitely check out http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Tables are not cross browser hell. They are the most reliable way of laying out something in a cross-browser fashion. However, doing that makes your html not be semantic as tables are meant for tabular data and not for layout. http://www.giveupandusetables.com/

Comment: The are not "the most reliable way of laying out something in a cross-browser fashion". Sorry Juan, that's just wrong. Tables are, as you point out yourself, for tabular data, not layout. The argument is so much more than semantic. As I said, tables do not respond well to Javascript animation in all browsers, and for good reason, they are tables, not layout elements. Have a look at the HTML5 spec which uses <header> and <section> and <footer> - that's the direction we should all be headed in. The table argument is dead. Don't dig it up.